# How to deal with missing data in both input and output sequences in RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, missing-data

For a time-series data D=[d1,d2,...,d20], 50% of the data is missing and marked as -1. I set my input data X = [d1,d2,...,d19], and output data as Y = [d2,d3,...,d20]. I wrote a many-to-many RNN, as shown below. To deal with the missing timestep in input sequence, I add a mask layer to avoid using the missing data in the training. For the missing timestep in output sequence, I wrote a custom loss function to avoid calculating the error at that position. There are a lot of methods dealing with missing input sequences, but I can't find any resources for the missing output sequence. Any suggestion or idea?

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    idx  = tf.not_equal(y_true, -1)
    y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, idx)
    y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, idx)
    return losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

def modelMask():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Masking(mask_value=-1, input_shape=(19, 1)))
  model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(19, 1)))
  model.add(LSTM(100, activation= 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(19))
  model.compile(loss = custom_loss, optimizer = 'adam', metrics = tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error)
  print(model.summary)
  return model
```